# Why am I not incrementing/decrementing correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cycle

I've been working on building a jquery cycle with custom animation and prev/next functionality. See [Old Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14075037/1905842). I haven't been able to figure out how to do this with cycle(). So I built this instead: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edubs/zmzzS/2/). However, as written, each function (prevcycle and nextcycle) only works once as I'm not correctly incrementing/decrementing my variables. What I'm doing wrong?

I'm new to all of this so all constructive criticism is welcome and appreciated.

Here is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var slideCount = $('div.slide').length,
    centSlide = 0, // enter 1 to test prevcycle
    prevSlide = centSlide - 1,
    nextSlide = centSlide + 1;

// initialize
$('.slide:eq('+centSlide+')').addClass('liveslide');
if (prevSlide >= 0 && prevSlide < slideCount) {
    $('.slide:eq('+prevSlide+')').addClass('prev');    
};
if (nextSlide < slideCount) {
    $('.slide:eq('+nextSlide+')').addClass('next');    
};

// next cycle code
$('.slide:eq('+nextSlide+')').click(function() {
    nextcycle(centSlide, slideCount);
});

// prev cycle code
$('.slide:eq('+prevSlide+')').click(function() {
    prevcycle(centSlide, slideCount);
});

// construct functions
function nextcycle(x, y) {
    centSlide = x + 1;
    prevSlide = centSlide - 1;
    nextSlide = centSlide + 1;

    $('.slide:eq('+x+')').removeClass('prev');
    $('.slide:eq('+centSlide+')').animate({
        left: 0,
        height: '90%',
        top: 0    
    }, 1000).removeClass('next').addClass('liveslide');
    if (prevSlide >= 0 && prevSlide < y) {
        $('.slide:eq('+prevSlide+')').animate({
        left: '-79%', 
        height: '80%',
        top: '5%',
    }, 1000).removeClass('liveslide').addClass('prev');    
    };
    if (nextSlide < y) {
        $('.slide:eq('+nextSlide+')').css('left','100%').animate({
        left: '79%'
        }, 1000).addClass('next')
    };
};

function prevcycle(x, y) {
    centSlide = x - 1;
    prevSlide = centSlide - 1;
    nextSlide = centSlide + 1;
    n = x + 1;

    $('.slide:eq('+n+')').removeClass('next');
    $('.slide:eq('+centSlide+')').animate({
        left: 0,
        height: '90%',
        top: 0    
    }, 1000).removeClass('prev').addClass('liveslide');
    if (prevSlide >= 0 && prevSlide < y) {
        $('.slide:eq('+prevSlide+')').css('left','-100%').animate({
        left: '-79%'
        }, 1000).addClass('prev');    
    };
    if (nextSlide < y) {
        $('.slide:eq('+nextSlide+')').animate({
        left: '79%', 
        height: '80%',
        top: '5%',
    }, 1000).removeClass('liveslide').addClass('next');    
    };
};

}); // end ready​
```

Comment: Is all of this code relevant to your question?

Comment: Looks like you're only adding the "click" handlers to a limited number of the elements.

Comment: @JamesHill - Honestly, I'm not sure. I believe my problem is how I'm incrementing/decrementing. But perhaps not.@Pointy - my intention is that the click events are assigned to the slides in the prevSlide and nextSlide positions, which change upon each click.

Comment: `eq` method will save you some bytes and improve readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting event listeners right at the start, when centSlide is 0... meaning that you're only listening to the events relative to their starting position.

I modified your click handlers to take into account the current value of centSlide and it's working great:

http://jsfiddle.net/hjNZD/

cheers

```
    $('.slide').click(function() {
      var index = $('.slide').index(this);
      if (index > centSlide) nextcycle(centSlide, slideCount);
      if (index < centSlide) prevcycle(centSlide, slideCount);
      return false;        
    });
```

Comment: If that answers your question, you should mark it as accepted so it can be useful to others in the future.